# Excel List Validation Conditions

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have a series of countries that have different available currencies and I want to set it up so that the Currency cell returns a specific list, depending on what country is inputted in the previous cell.

**Example:**

My cell, B1 contains the *Country*, in this example "United Kingdom"

Cell C1, which returns the *Currency*, should output a list containing "GBP and USD"

In the case where cell B1 is "United States", Cell C1 should return a list containing "USD"

I attempted to add a Custom Data Validation using this code, however, nothing is outputted.
*** *Note, the United_Kingdom, United_States, etc. are selected lists with specified names.*

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2="United Kingdom";United_Kingdom;IF(B2="United States";United_States;IF(B2="Canada";Canada;IF(B2="Denmark";Denmark;IF(B2="Switzerland";Switzerland;IF(B2="Norway";Norway;IF(B2="Sweden";Sweden;)))))));EUR)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you give a screenshot as well?

Comment: For the first image, since B1 is "United Kingdom", C1 should have a list with options "USD or GBP". For the second image I simply am showing you the lists, with specified names.

Comment: INDEX(MATCH) is really a great way to do it. Try it a bit yourself, I will post it in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `index(match)` is the correct way to do something like this, avoiding nested `ifs`. This is how the formula should look like:

[image]

**Edit**
If you want to be able to choose the Currency, then you may need an additional parameter. In this case it is 3 and it chooses the second currency, if available:

[image]

These guys have written good instructions for `Index(Match)` - https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact

Comment: For the example County="UK" I need to have options for the Currency to be either USD or GBP, not USD/GBP. Otherwise, thank you and I will definitely use Index(match) from now on.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did to solve my answer was simple and don't know why it didn't work before.

I simply used this code in the Data Validation List section.

```
=IF(B2="Canada";CA;IF(B2="Switzerland";CH;IF(B2="Denmark";DK;IF(B2="Norway";NO;IF(B2="Sweden";SE;IF(B2="United Kingdom";UK;IF(B2="United States";US;EUR)))))))
```

I also proceeded to add the following code to the cell itself, so that it enters data automatically, ultimately saving time.

```
=IF(B8="";"";IF(B8="United States";"USD";IF(B8="United Kingdom";"";IF(B8="Norway";"NOK";IF(B8="Sweden";"SEK";IF(B8="Canada";"CAD";IF(B8="Switzerland";"CHF";"EUR")))))))
```

Comment: Have you tested your solution with "United Kingdom"?  Your question makes it look like you want to display "USD/GBP".  In your answer here it looks like it will display nothing.